# Other ways to express: 'get more out' (of something)?

Tags: expressions

> "I need to learn more about other  countries and people, that's why I am going to travel. When I come back **I will get more out** of my studies".

*Get more out?* This  is the expression that I can get.

By the way, my book give me some explanation to this expression:

> "learn more from..."

Could you give any other examples with this expression, please?

I will be so happy if you answer it, because tomorrow will be my English exam.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example, "... get more out of..." means that the person will gain a greater understanding - learn more - from their studies after the trip.  Literally, they will "get more [learning] out of" the studies than they otherwise would have.  To me, it implies that the person is traveling, and believes that having actually been to other countries and met other people will assist them in their studies more than simply book learning would have.

Another example might be: "I will *get more out of* my workout because swimsuit season is coming."  The person knows they want to lose pounds fast, so they are motivated to do more.

Answer (score 1):

Another phrase I can think of that means something similar is "get better value from" my studies.

The key word here is "value". I think "value" is a good concept to understand. I'm going to define "value" as actually "using" your knowledge and making it a part of your life rather than just memorizing things.

So, to recap: you will "get more out of" your studies if you travel because you'll be able to connect your "knowledge" to your "experience" and get better "value".